# How to install package from newer distribution?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, package-management

I have Ubuntu 10.04 server and want to update a package to newer version (update rrdtool from 1.3.8 to current 1.4.5). What should I do? Download and build sources or get package from newer distribution? And how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the repositories of the newer release to `sources.list`, then configure *[apt-pinning](https://www.google.com/search?q=apt-pinning)* to give priority to the current release despite it being older. (See docs on [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences), [elsewhere](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html).)

You will then be able to specify the newer repository when installing packages, but the system will remain at its current release.

However, newer packages often pull in *more* newer packages (libraries, other dependencies) which in turn may pull in *even more*, and you might soon wind up upgrading things like 'glibc' just to satisfy the dependencies of a single program, at which point upgrading the entire system to the newer release would be the only way to un-break the system.

Alternatively, you could download the sources – either directly from the developers, or from Ubuntu packagers using `apt-get -t newer-repo source rrdtool`, then compile it locally (using `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` if you downloaded the Ubuntu source package). This will be easier on the dependencies, but will have to be updated manually.